# how to intent with on click button from activity to fragment in android studio

Tags: java, android

how to intent with on click button from activity to fragment in android studio. please anyone tell me what is exact code to intent from activity to fragment with button click on activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button mButNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
        mButNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(this, PropertyListFragment.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
   }
}
```

PropertyListFragment.class

```
public class PropertyListFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    public static PropertyListFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        PropertyListFragment fragment = new PropertyListFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PropertyListFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        String strtext = getArguments().getString("pincode");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_property_list, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

fragment_property_list.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/sample_content_fragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Button mButNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
        mButNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                PropertyListFragment plf = PropertyListFragment.newInstance("param1", "param2"); 
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, plf, "tag").commit();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You use an Intent to open another Activity.

If your goal is to show the Fragment in it's own Activity then create an intent to start the new Activity, and have the target Activity load your Fragment in onCreate. See [Adding a Fragment to an Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding)

If your goal is to show the Fragment in the same Activity then read slightly further down in the previous link about programmatically add the fragment to an existing ViewGroup